# Unit testing asp.net mvc controller action tryupdate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, tdd, code-coverage

I wanna test the controller action, but one point is not coveraged by visual studio Code coverage tool.

```
    public ActionResult Activate(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
            return View("PageNotFound");

        var city = repository.GetCityById(id.Value);

        if (city == null)
            return View("PageNotFound");


        city.IsActive = !city.IsActive;

        if (TryUpdateModel(city))
        {
            repository.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("MyCities");
        }

        ***return View("PageNotFound");***
    }
```

in the code coverage, ******return View("PageNotFound");** is not coveraged.
Because, I can not simulate the TryUpdateModel false stuation. TryUpdateModel can get false if model can not updated. Can u help about this?

Comment: To be honest I don't think you need to provide a unit test for that scenario.  I think it should be part of your coding debugging and testing.  The only method I would probably unit test in that example is the GetCityById()

Answer (score 0):

`TryUpdateModel` will return false if the model validation fails.
(in which case you should not be showing a not found page)

Comment: TryUpdateModel will return false if the model validation fails, but I can not simulate the model validation false stuation in unit testing.

Answer (score 0):

In situations like these there are all kinds of options for you. One of them is creating a stub  that overrides the actual functionality of the method you want to control.

For example, you can declare `TryUpdateModel` as virtual. In your unit test, instead of working with the original class, you inherit it and override the TryGetModel to simply return false. All other functionality is retained as is.

Now you call the `Activate` method on the derived class that has the exact same functionality apart from the simulated `TryUpdateModel` method, allowing you to test the desired use case without breaking your head as how to simulate a certain execution path.

This technique is not without drawbacks: it makes you declare the method as virtual only for testing purposes, thus preventing you from making it sealed, or static. There are other, more advanced techniques ([Mock objects](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-mocktest/index.html), [isolation frameworks](http://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page)) but I think that this is a good enough solution for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You don't include code to show how the lifetime of the **cargo** dependency is handled, so I'm only guessing, but...

It should be possible to pass a mock or fake instance of this class to the controller as part of your test setup (if it isn't currently possible, refactor until it is).

With the mock in place you can isolate and test the behaviour as you want.

Aside: I disagree with the comment from @dreza... testing this sort of business logic is very important.

I would also caution against faking the implementation of TryUpdateModel as suggested by @Vitaliy, after all you want to test what happens if the cargo model is invalid (not just *pretend that it is* by providing a new version of core code).

Answer (score 0):

OK,
I solved solution. I deleted the TryUpdatemodel if condition. Directly used repository.Save() method. Because I did not send parameter a model to activate method.